# Is this better/quicker to return a count than returning an object? stack overflow!

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm creating a repository in EF4. For one of the methods a password and username is used to verify a user. The method returns a count of users so a 0 means they don't exist and a 1 they do. Would it make much of a difference if I just returned a user object and checked it for null?

Comment: You are the one to determine if it's *better*, because we don't know what you intend to do with the result. If you never intend to use any of the user data that could be returned, why return it? However, if you find that you *will* need it, and then you proceed to make *another* trip to the database to get it after you've returned your count, then *why not just return the object in the first place?* You need to determine what your requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the most efficient way would probably be to use the `Any()` extension method.  If you return an object there is the cost of filling that object.  If you return a count, then there is the cost of going through every record (after the where clause has been applied) and counting them. `Any()` should use `Exists` in sql, and therefore, SQL server can stop as soon as it finds the first record.

Ultimately though, I agree with the others, this isn't a place you want to start optimizing right away.  Donald Knuth probably has the best quote about this:
"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil".

For instance, let's say you have this method return a bool and you use the `Any()` method.  Later in the request, you might need to pull the user object out of the database (this could be something you end up doing a lot).  Now, by optimizing early, you've actually increased the number of calls to the database.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

well the option with Any is going to be better because EF has a high cost of materialization and change tracking for an object and if that object happens to have lot of properties, you should definitely consider using Any.

Answer (score 0):

The second version would be better - in terms of design. In terms of microefficiency it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Hoakey if you want to know the truth. Both methods are going to be so negligible that it wont matter which one you choose. Choose whichever method makes your code easier to understand and read. Often times people get worried about performance in all the wrong places.

I agree with Armen, return the object and check for null. Very simple and is easy to understand what is going on.

Comment: If I'm going to return the object, would you recommend saving in session? The reason I ask is that depending o the choices the user makes, these details could be used later on. Or would you do a seperate call if and when they're required?

Comment: Assuming you're using a Web based application. Normally in this situation I only store user details in request cache, because I have external services which can modify the data in the database which make syncing up the in memory cache of a session difficult. It was easier for me to get fresh data from the database on each web request. But i would defiantly cache it on the request level.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any data from the 'user' table after you verify that a valid user/password combo exists, then either method will work (and performance won't matter).

On the other hand, if once you verify valid username/password you plan on making a second call to get the user details, then clearly returning the object in the first place(and checking for null to verify existence) is a more efficient strategy in my opinion.